# docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase. See 'docker run --help'

Tags: docker, rendering, intel-oneapi, intel-renderkit

I am following the URL:

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-intel-oneapi-render-linux/top/configure-your-system.html#34C71E32-E697-4852-BA15-DA379EF200A2

Error generating step:-

Run the Docker and work from a container:

If you have proxy set up:

```
sudo -E docker run --name renderkit --rm -it --privileged -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/ tmp/.X11-unix -e HTTP_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY -e HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTPS_PROXY -e http_proxy=$http_proxy -e https_proxy=$https_proxy ubuntu bash
```

Error:-

```
docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: Is there an extra space in the `-v ...:/ tmp/.X11-unix` option?  That could cause this error.  (`sudo -E -i` is a much easier way to get a root shell, that can perform any action on the host, access the host display, and use the predefined proxy variables.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below command works:

```
sudo -E docker run --name renderkit --rm -it --privileged -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e HTTP_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY -e HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTPS_PROXY -e http_proxy=$http_proxy -e https_proxy=$https_proxy ubuntu bash
```

There is small correction in the command, an extra space added after "/" tmp